# How to store array elements in an Excel Sheet cells with TCL/tcom

Tags: excel, tcl

I want to store array elements in an Excel Sheet. How can I do that?
Here is the sample code for an array:

```
for {set i 0} { $i < 3} {incr i} {
    set color($i) $i    
}
```

Now how can I store color(0), color(1), color(2) in different cells?

**Edit:**
Based on this [tcom example](http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/excel.html) I have been trying to store array elements in an Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the commands [`array set`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/array.htm#M11) and [`array get`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/array.htm#M8).

```
for {set i 0} { $i < 3} {incr i} {
    set color($i) $i    
}

set nvList [array get color]
```

Variable `nvList` has now the value `0 0 1 1 2 2` (mind the comments). With `array get` you get the Name-Value representation of an array. If you call `array set` you can convert `nvList` to an array again.

It this what you need?

**Edit:** Another example based on your comment:

```
# building example array with 100 elements
for {set r 1} {$r <= 100} {incr r} {
    set color($r) $r
}

set rows [array size color]
set columns {A B C}

for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    foreach column $columns {
        $cells Item $row $column $color($row)
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Another (second) example based on your comment:

```
array set atten {...}
array set transmit {...}

set rows [array size atten]
for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    $cells Item $row "B" $atten($row)
} 

set rows [array size transmit]
for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    $cells Item $row "C" $transmit($row)
}
```

Comment: It _could_ be `0 0 2 2 1 1` or `1 1 0 0 2 2` or any other reordering of the pairs; Tcl doesn't guarantee traversal key order in the `array get` command.

Comment: Does it matter? I think for this example it doesn't.

Comment: set application [::tcom::ref createobject "Excel.Application"]
 $application Visible 1
 set workbooks [$application Workbooks]
 $workbooks Add [::tcom::na]
 set workbook [$workbooks Item "Book1"]
 set worksheets [$workbook Worksheets]
 set worksheet [$worksheets Item "Sheet1"]
 set cells [$worksheet Cells]
 set i 0
 set nvList [array get color]

Comment: #set x "1 2 3"
  foreach row $nvlist{
  foreach column { B } {
         #$cells Item $row $column [incr i]
   $cells Item $row $column "$color($i)"
   incr i
                          }
                 } 
  
  ::tcom::dispatch $workbook SaveAs Filename {c:\tst.xls}
 $application Quit

 ::tcom::release $cells $worksheet $worksheets $workbook $workbooks
 ::tcom::release $application

Comment: @user1226507 Can you be more specific? What is your problem?

Comment: This is the code im using to print some data to excel. It actually works if i set static value to the variable row such as foreach row $x where x = "1 2 3" where as when i tried to use set nvList [array get color] and use foreach row $nvlist i get an unknown error... can anyone help me out here

Comment: Look at this example http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/excel.html Do you understand what this is doing?

Comment: Yes i used the same example. Now i have an array and i need to write that array to a column in excel. How can i do that based on the example stated in vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/excel.html ?

Comment: @alexvetter i don't want to use the statement set rows {1 2 3}, also i dont have indexes such as 1,2,3 in the array set color {1 "red" 2 "blue" 3 "green"} .. I want to pass length of the array to the value rows something like {1 . . .length(array)}. Is there any option do this?

Comment: @alexvetter lets say i have an array with many elements and i have to pass the lenghth of the array to the value rows in the foreach loop. How can i do that?

Comment: Though im able to populate the data on the excel there is an error called invalid command name "::tcom::dispatch".. any idea on this?

Comment: Have a look at the example again (http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/excel.html). tcom::dispatch anyway? This command doesn't exist (anymore). I think you don't need it.

Comment: And have a look at the api of tcom (http://www.vex.net/~cthuang/tcom/tcom.n.html)

Comment: set a_rows [array size transmit]
set a_columns { C}

for {set row 1} {$row <= $a_rows} {incr row} {
    foreach column $a_columns {
        $cells Item $row $column $transmit($row)
    }
}

Comment: when i try to add this set of lines after i write my first array to the excel, the new array transmit is not added to the column C.

Comment: set rows [array size atten]
set columns { B}

for {set row 1} {$row <= $rows} {incr row} {
    foreach column $columns {
        $cells Item $row $column $atten($row)
    }
} this is the code to add the first array to excel

Comment: @alexvetter still have the same problem .. Still the data in the first array atten alone is populated in the Column B of the excel. The Column C is empty..

Comment: What happens if you "close" the excel file start over again and than do the column C?

Comment: @alexvetter thanks it works now, i  add some error in my code.. it works fine now