# Store struct in excel cells?

Tags: excel, data-structures, excel-formula

Hey guys,

Is there a way to store a data struct inside an excel cell? How would I put and get data from it?

I expect to use something like

to put struct in cell A1: `=putstruct("data1", 123, "data2", "hello", "data3", MMULT(matA,matB))`

to get in cell B1 from A1: `=getstruct("A1", "data1")`

One (of several) problems solved with a struct: if I need to reference a computed matrix, first I gotta expand (i.e. display) the whole matrix on the spreadsheet and then name it as a range to start using it. But if the matrix size changes, that starts to become a headache...

Any help appreciated!

<sub>By the way, I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162854/using-excel-add-ins-to-store-complex-structures-with-vba-in-excel) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575299/how-to-store-array-elements-in-an-excel-sheet-cells-with-tcl-tcom)</sub>

Comment: are you using vba at all? wouldn't a multi dimensional array suffice for creating a dynamic matrix?

Comment: @scott I can't think of a way VBA would help on storing data structures into the worksheet cells.. do you have a tip?

Comment: How exactly do you want to cram that much data in a single cell ? In my experience that would be an absurd way to work. I had to debug a macro that kept crashing because people put 2-3 dates in a single cell just this week and it was horrible. Why do you want to do this to yourself ?

Comment: @Alexandre P. Levasseur well I guess that was horrible, but I'm sure they weren't working with structured data though..

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible to do but complex. 
putstruct needs to store the data in some internal global data pool with a handle and put the handle to the data structure in A1.
 
Then Getstruct uses the handle in A1 to return the data. 
 Some of the difficulties involved are;

making GetStruct return data correctly whenever the data changes  
  persisting the global data in a saved workbook so that it reappears    when the workbook is opened
 cleaning up the global data when the cell    with the handle is overwritten or deleted

Comment: as a starter, I merely thought of parsing a string stored inside A1... but intuition says that solution would crash

Comment: what 'some internal global data pool' would be? Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: There are many alternatives - global variant arrays, custom XML parts, Excel Binary Names, ranges in very-hidden sheets, Collections, Dictionaries, Maps, xlOpers ... depends on what your specific circumstances and technologies are.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you... 
first run this macro in a new workbook:

```
Sub AddMacroFunctions()
 Sheets.Add Type:=xlExcel4MacroSheet
 [B2] = "=ARGUMENT(""Name"",2)"
 [B3] = "=ARGUMENT(""Value"",95)"
 [B4] = "=RETURN(SET.NAME(Name,Value))"
 [B6] = "=RESULT(95)"
 [B7] = "=ARGUMENT(""Value"",95)"
 [B8] = "=RETURN(EVALUATE(Value))"
 Names.Add "Put", Range("B2"), , xlFunction
 Names.Add "Get", Range("B6"), , xlFunction
 ActiveSheet.Visible = False
End Sub
```

...now for the given example you could enter these formulas on the activesheet:

```
A1: =AND(Put("data1",123),Put("data2","hello"),Put("data3",MMULT({1;2},{3,4})))
B1: =IF(A1,Get("data1"))
```

The data will be stored in the macrosheet that is created with the macro. If you change the value in the formula in `A1`, the value in `B1` automatically updates.

This could also be adapted to the putstruct / getstruct methodology by storing data in a custom name like `mystruct.data1` and the workbook could be saved as an addin so the functions are accessible from any workbook.